# How to add module namespace to a ruby class/module?

Tags: ruby, namespaces

I want to add a namespace to a class/module I'm defining, but I don't want to type in the long format

`class A::B::C::D::<ClassName>`

OR

```
module A
  module B
    module C
      module D
        class ClassName
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In other words, I just want to define the class `class ClassName` and then need a way to send this class to live under the namespace `A::B::C::D`

So that I can write a bunch of code like so:

```
# File Name: a/b/c/d/some_class.rb
class SomeClass
  include SomeModule
  # class content
end

# File Name: a/b/c/d/some_module.rb
module SomeModule
  # module content
end
```

Because there are too many modules in my codebase, I don't want to type in the prefixing namespace everytime. But I want to say something like this at the end:

```
SomeClass.add_to_namespace(A::B::C::D)
SomeModule.add_to_namespace(A::B::C::D)
```

**Important:** This should also affect class namespace lookup so that Ruby/Rails doesn't complain like:

`expected a/b/c/d/some_class.rb to define SomeClass`

Question: Will `include`-ing my class in the namespace have the same effect?

```
module A::B::C::D
  include ClassName
end
```

Comment: Why not write a quick'n'dirty shell script with a bit of `sed`?

Comment: _"I don't want to type in the long format"_ – you mean when creating a new class / module?

Comment: @Stefan yes while creating the class/module

Comment: This sounds like something your editor / IDE should help you with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you're asking is kinda multi-faceted, but if you just want to use the class in another file without having to type out the namespace each time then a simple solution would just be to redefine it in the file you want to use it in

```
ClassName = A::B::C::D::ClassName
```

Then you can just do `ClassName.method` just fine